# Why does the app crash when using CAGradientLayer

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, quartz-graphics

I've started using the CAGradientLayer but my app crashes

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = headerView.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor redColor],(id)[UIColor greenColor], nil];

[headerView.layer addSublayer:gradient];
```

EXEC_BAD_ACESS

Is there an error in my implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a small bug - you need to use and array of `CGColorRef` pointers:

```
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor], nil];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, is there a reason why it's not validated at compile time?

Comment: That's a good question - Objective-C uses a dynamic runtime, so when creating an array, the compiler doesn't really care *what* is in the array. It's these types of compile-time sanity checks that we lose when we use a dynamic runtime, but it's worth it :)

Answer (score 2):

CAGradientLayer use CGColorRef values.  Use the CGColor property for UIColor.    Example:

```
[UIColor redColor].CGColor
```